# Page redirect query

Tags: php

When my user enters their email and password into a form on login.php, the form action uses the below code to make sure they are a valid user, and that neither of the fields are blank. My problem is that even when valid email and password is used the user is directed back to the login.php page instead of the logged_in.php lage, can anyone suggest why?

```
<?php
        session_start();

        include("connection.inc.php");
        $connection = connect();

        $txtEmail = $_POST['email'];
        $txtPassword = $_POST['password'];

        if ((empty($txtEmail)) || (empty($txtPassword)))
        {
            header("Location: login.php");
            exit;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE email = '$txtEmail' AND password = '$txtPassword'";

        $result = @mysql_query($sql) or die ("Unable to run query");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($count != 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $txtEmail;
            $_SESSION['attempt_info'] = "authenticated";
            header("Location: logged_in.php");
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($count)` display? You should also consider using prepared statements, or at least santizing your `$txtEmail` and `$txtPassword` variables as you are currently open to SQL injections

Comment: +1 for @jprofitt regarding SQL injections. Plus, storing passwords as plain text is not good practice - consider storing them as hashes (could be as simple as using SHA1). Regarding the result, I would echo out the prepared `$sql` statement, run it from the command line or PhpMyAdmin and check that results are coming back.

Comment: I've occassionally seen header redirects allow the code to continue to run - consider adding a `die();` after the `header("...` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though `$txtEmail` is your variable and `email` its its name in the sql database, so it should look like this

```
$txtEmail = $_POST['txtEmail'];
$txtPassword = $_POST['txtPassword'];
```

This will allow the contents of your text field to be passed to the sql query.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually redirecting to `login.php` in the last `if`-statement. I think it should be redirecting to `logged_in.php`, if the SQL query succeeds.

Comment: I've tried this also and reuploaded to the server, this also does not work

Comment: I didn't even look closely at the query at first, but I cannot see something wrong with it, except for injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($txtEmail) or empty($txtPassword))
     {
                 // ...
     }

 if($count ==1) //something can go wrong set the 0 to 1
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $txtEmail;
            $_SESSION['attempt_info'] = "authenticated";
            header("Location: logged_in.php");
        }
```

Comment: Changing to a 1 doesn't appear to make a difference, i am still taken back to the login.php page